# What is the use of cleaned_data in Django

Tags: django, cleaned-data

Django says if `form.is_valid()` is `True`.  `form.cleaned_data` is where all validated fields are stored. But I am confused about using the `cleaned_data` function.

`form.cleaned_data['f1']` -- cleaned data
`request.POST.get('f1')` -- un-validated data

I have a model form in Django.

```
if form1.is_valid():
    form1.save()
```

Does this save cleaned_data to the model or does it save unvalidated data.

```
form2=form1.save(commit=False);
```

Does form2 contain form1's cleaned_data or unvalidated data.

Apart from converting any date to python datetime object, is there a good example of benefit of using cleaned_data vs unvalidated data.
Thanks

Comment: Why would it save uncleaned data? Anyway, if the form is valid, there isn't any uncleaned data.

Comment: So form1.cleaned_data[' ']  should only be used when checking individual form field? And if form.is_valid() ==True, then there is no need to access individual field cleaned_data.
 form1['field1'] == form1.cleaned_data['field1'] ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There 2 situations: using basic **Form** (forms.Form)  and **ModelForm** (forms.ModelForm).

If you are using a ModelForm then there is no any need of playing with a `cleaned_data` dictionary because when you do `form.save()` it is already be matched and the clean data is saved. But you are using basic Form then you have to manually match each `cleaned_data` to its database place and then save the instance to the database not the form.

For example **basic Form**:

```
if form.is_valid():
    ex = Example()
    ex.username = form.cleaned_data['username']
    ex.save()
```

For example **ModelForm**:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

**NOTE:** If the form pass from `is_valid()` stage then there is no any unvalidated data.

Comment: `form1.save()` or `form2=form1.save(commit=False)` wont work if form is invalid. Which also means that these functions only save valid inputs to DB.

Use `python manage.py shell` to try it out

Comment: Yes that is right. That is why they are put in is_valid() clause. Django tries to make everything error free and without it you should yourself had to validate the input data.

Answer (score 40):

#### TL;DR

`form.cleaned_data` returns a dictionary of validated form input fields and their values, where string primary keys are returned as objects.

`form.data` returns a dictionary of un-validated form input fields and their values in string format (i.e. not objects).

#### Example by code

In my `forms.py` I have two fields:

```
class Loginform(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField()
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

and in my `views.py`:

```
def login_page(request):
    form=Loginform(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
```

The above code prints the following output:

```
{'username': 'xyz', 'password': 'shinchan'}
```

If instead `views.py` contains:

```
def login_page(request):
    form=Loginform(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form)
```

The above code prints the following:

```
 <tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="username" value="xyz" required id="id_username"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td><input type="password" name="password" required id="id_password"></td></tr>
```